# How to make cloud flow dataverse connection act as / impersonate the canvas app user that triggered the flow?

Tags: power-automate, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

What I did, as user A:

1. New Powerapps environment with dataverse DB, within the new environment...
2. New solution, within the new solution...
3. New Dataverse table
4. New Canvas App with a button wired to...
5. New Cloud Flow, creation triggered from within the canvas app editor. Cloud flow uses `PowerApps (V2)` trigger and has only one dataverse `Add a new row` action, which inserts a record into the table created above
6. Published the entire solution (still same env)
7. Successfully tested if I could insert through the canvas app's button, which in turn only calls the cloud flow.
8. Shared the app with user B

Ran the canvas app as user B, hit the same button:

- Cloud flow runs successfully
- New record is properly inserted

However, the record's `created by` columns shows User A (instead of user B).
I would need User B to show as record creator.

Is my expectation wrong and this is just not possible with Powerapp triggered cloud flows, or am I missing something?

Also, I found this encouraging [post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/How-do-I-manage-run-only-users-in-microsoft-flow/td-p/355293), but it didn't provide any specific solution that Ii could apply.

Comment: Hmmmm, does this help ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2022wave1/power-automate/use-connections-provided-run-only-users-dataverse-connector

Comment: Than you for sharing this @Skin, it actually supports my expectation of how it should / could behave. But I can not find any details whatsoever in how to use this feature.

Comment: Well ... it says it hasn't been released yet so I'd suggest a matter of waiting is in order.